# jquery script doesnt work in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, thumbnails

when i click on thumbnails, this script change the link and image path of the big picture, it works fine in all the browsers, except for ) IE

```
    $('.image').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imagePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var newImg = new Image;
    newImg.src = imagePath;
    newImg.onload = function(){
        $('#big_picture2').hide();
        $('#big_picture2').attr('src', imagePath);
        $('.product_image_large').attr('href', imagePath);
        $('#big_picture2').fadeIn('slow');
    };
});
```

the html looks like this:

```
<a href="/documents/product/#GET_IMAGE_BIG.path#" id="thumb1" onclick="return hs.expand(this, { slideshowGroup: 1 } )" class="product_image_large"><img src="/documents/product/#path#" id="big_picture2" border="0" /></a>

<a href="/documents/product/#get_product_images.path#" class="image"><cf_get_server_file output_file="product/#get_product_images.path#" title="#get_product_images.detail#" output_server="#path_server_id#" output_type="0" image_width="45" image_height="41"></a>
```

dont get disturbed by cf_get_server_file this is just dynamic cold fusion code, it works fine.

Comment: sorry didnt define it, it is 8th

Comment: do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: Have you tried moving the line where you set `newImg.src` to *after* the point where you set up the "onload" handler?

Comment: @Pointy oops, we had the same thought at the same time. Didn't steal from you, honest :)

Comment: @Pointy no difference at all.. :(

Comment: Well, @abrabr, what **does** happen?  Have you used the IE8 debugger to check whether the image "load" handler is called at all?

Comment: @Pointy and @Pekka ) u're right guys! thank you! didnt refresh page properly before ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this solves the whole problem, but you are setting the `onload` event after defining the `src` property. That is calling for trouble. Do it the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

`onLoad` will not trigger in IE if the image is allready cached, try checking for the `complete` attribute which IE will add when the image is loaded.

```
newImg.src = imagePath;
var fadeIn = function(){
    $('#big_picture2').hide();
    $('#big_picture2').attr('src', imagePath);
    $('.product_image_large').attr('href', imagePath);
    $('#big_picture2').fadeIn('slow');
};
if($(newImg).attr('complete'))
{
    fadeIn();
}
else
{
    newImg.onLoad = fadeIn
}
```

Comment: this script didnt help though

Answer (score 0):

Add `$(document).ready()` around.

Comment: certainly not this ) i defined it